# Getting index of a certain element in a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, dynamic-arrays

I'm new to python so I need some help with this:

I have 2D array of numbers that represent density of a circle of material in a space and I want to locate the centre.
So I want to get the index of the numbers representing the diameter and then the middle index will be the centre. In this code I only store the value of the density : tempdiameter.append(cell) 
I want the index of the cell itself. How can I do that.
Also I don't want to use lists for diameter. so how can I create a dynamic 1D np array? 
Thanks

```
for row in x:
    for cell in row:
        if cell!=0:
            tempdensity+=cell
            tempdiameter.append(cell)

    if tempdensity>maxdensity:
            maxdensity=tempdensity
            if len(tempdiameter)>=len(diameter):
                   diameter=tempdiameter

    tempdensity=0
    tempdiameter=[]
```

Comment: to be more clear and help us to be useful. can you give a simple example of your data and what do you want to do with? a simple input, output will be perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the row with the highest number of non-zero cells and the highest sum you can do

```
 densities = x.sum(axis=1)
 lengths = (x > 0).sum(axis=1)
 center = x[(densities == densities.max()) & (lengths == lengths.max()]
```

Try to avoid using loops in `numpy`. Let me know if this isn't what you want and I'll try to answer it better. You should provide sample input/output when asking a question. You can also edit your question rather than adding comments.

Comment: yes I'm trying to reach the longest row with non-zero values and with largest density sum. which should correspond to the diameter of the circle and then by storing all indices of these non/zero elements..the middle index should be the center of the circle and half the length of the index list is the radius.

so here is a 5x5 sample 2D numpy array:
[[ 0.   0.   0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.2  0.4  0.2  0. ]
 [ 0.   0.4  1.   0.4  0. ]
 [ 0.   0.2  0.4  0.2  0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.   0.   0. ]]

Comment: and the output should be :
maximum density line:1.8 which correspond to density of diameter

diameter length = 3
radius = 1.5
area = 7.06858347058
center location = [2, 2]
I will try what you wrote now..thanks for helping
I can use polygon module for recognising geometries like that,right?

Comment: since I can't edit 1st comment anymore, here is what I want clearly.the array actually is expected to be 1000x500 with more that one circle inside. and I want to get the center of every one of them and also the radius so that I can calculate area and plot an image. is there a well know way to do that? the output to this example should be [2,2] center position and 1.5 radius. Thanks and sorry for the multiple comments, it's my 1st post
   `[[ 0.   0.   0.   0.   0. ]`
   `[ 0.   0.2  0.4  0.2  0. ]`
   `[ 0.   0.4  1.   0.4  0. ]`
   `[ 0.   0.2  0.4  0.2  0. ]`
   `[ 0.   0.   0.   0.   0. ]]`

Comment: argmax won't work because there will be definitely more than one element having the same density value 1 which is the highest and I just want the one in the middle, the center.
and someone tell how to write code in comments so that I can write my code here

Comment: I've edited the answer but still not sure if it's what you want. It seems to be from the small example you give. I'm not familiar with this matrix representation of a circle so maybe I'm not the best person to answer.